# This gives me response in console but i want response in a variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, console, alert

I want to convert it to jquery and store response in a variable and show it in an alert box

```
(function () {var s = document.createElement('script');var h = document.querySelector('head') || document.body;s.src = 'https://acsbapp.com/apps/app/dist/js/app.js';s.async = true; s.onload = function () {acsbJS.init({statementLink: '', footerHtml: '', hideMobile: false, hideTrigger: false,disableBgProcess: false, language: 'en', position: 'right',leadColor: '#146FF8',triggerColor: '#146FF8', triggerRadius: '50%',                    triggerPositionX: 'right',triggerPositionY: 'bottom', triggerIcon: 'people',triggerSize: 'bottom', triggerOffsetX: 20,triggerOffsetY: 20, mobile: {triggerSize: 'small', triggerPositionX: 'right', triggerPositionY: 'bottom',triggerOffsetX: 20, triggerOffsetY: 20, triggerRadius: '20'}});};h.appendChild(s);})();
```

I tried calling it from jquery but it is not giving me the desired result

Even if I could get response in variable using JavaScript would work

```
        $.Ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("https://acsbapp.com/apps/app/dist/js/app.js")',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: { Section: 'Notification', mode: 'add' },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () { },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```